# Existing React Native app in Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have an existing React Native app. I tried to set up a new Google Analytics property for it, but GA forces me to use Firebase. In Firebase, I see that I can add separate Android and iOS applications, but I can't see a way to add my app as a single entity. Before Google started pushing Firebase, I was able to set up a new tracking ID for a mobile app and collect all Android and iOS data together under the single RN app.

Is creating separate iOS and Android applications in Firebase the correct way to get analytics data for my one React Native application? It seems like my analytics data will be fragmented, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to Google, and Firebase does not support React Native – which is why I couldn’t find a way to add a single RN application rather than separate iOS and Android ones.

Google tells me I don’t actually need to use Firebase after all. I'm supposed to set up my mobile app as a website with some fake data (site URL, etc.) and then spawn a mobile view from that property. It’s a hack, but it’s what they recommend.